# Trying VNC for first time (debian based)

Tags: linux, debian, vnc

I've never used a VNC or any remote login programme before So I'm trying to use TigerVNC. However, I'm open to suggestions, I'm happy to try any VNC programme, I just want to get something working. I've also vaguely heard of TightVNC and X11VNC. I have no idea if these are Free and open source (which is a prerequisite) but I'm mainly interested in ease of use and simple step by step documentation, as I unfortunately only have about 20 minutes a day/night to spend on things like this.

I have set up two MX 19.3 (i.e. debian based) computers and I'm trying to remotely access between them. I've installed tigervnc viewer and tiger standalone server but when I try the following commands I'm getting the following issues:

Code: Select all

---

> ```
> $ sh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l Robserver 192. ... . ...
> ssh: connect to host 192. ... . ... port 22: Connection refused
> ```

---

> ```
> $ vncserver -list
>
> TigerVNC server sessions:
>
> X DISPLAY #   RFB PORT #  PROCESS ID
> ```

---

> ```
> $ vncserver
>
> New 'Rob:1 (Rob)' desktop at :1 on machine Rob
>
> Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
> Log file is /home/Rob/.vnc/Rob:1.log
>
> Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /home/Rob/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
>
>
> vncserver: Failed command '/etc/X11/Xvnc-session': 256!
>
> =================== tail -15 /home/Rob/.vnc/Rob:1.log ===================
> Underlying X server release 12004000, The X.Org Foundation
>
>
> Wed May 26 21:27:33 2021
>  vncext:      VNC extension running!
>  vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5901
>  vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
> XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
>       after 173 requests (173 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
> The server closed the connection.
>
> Wed May 26 21:27:34 2021
>  ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
>  ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
> Killing Xtigervnc process ID 677... which seems to be deadlocked. Using SIGKILL!
>
> =========================================================================
>
> Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session has failed.
> Maybe try something simple first, e.g.,
>   tigervncserver -xstartup /usr/bin/xterm
> ```

I really don't know what I'm doing and I have a weak grasp on the key concepts, so I probably did something wrong (like setting-up to start on boot, how SSH works, firewall, ports). I was just following a couple guides online and I probably misapplied them. One thing I found was that they weren't clear on what to do on the server and what do to on the client, there is no differentiation. I wanted an idiots guide which said something like 'okay now write down that server I.P address and type it in on your VNC viewer' etc.
Does anyone have any suggestions for a novice using MX linux?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late... and no skill with MX !

As you said, you need one computer acting as "server" (the one you'll get the display), and one acting as "client" (the one you really use and really type on a real keyboard and watch/use the remote display of the "server").
You'll -probably- need to know the IP of the computers : `ip a s` should give you the answer.

In your case, I assume MX are desktops and you want to get the running GUI of the other computer. I'll try to explain a simple bare connection between both computers. The connection are NOT save : nothing is secured, passworded, encrypted : I assume both MX are on you LAN behind a good firewall. If you need more security, it is possible but not in those explanation yet. This connection could be reversed : just invert everything.

On your "client" (for my example, it'll had IP 192.168.1.14), I propose you to use the often already installed Gnome's "Remote Desktop Viewer" aka "Vinagre", or (my preferate) "Remmina" installed with a simple `apt install remmina`. Others exist...

On your "server" (for my example, it'll had IP 192.168.1.25) , use x11vnc as it is perfect for sharing an already open graphical session. Install it with an `apt install x11vnc`.

Now, you have two possibilities :

1. The server is offering a connection (usually on port 5900 or a bit more) and the client try to connect there (you need to know the server's IP) :

- From your "server" (directly or SSHed from the "client"), as the current user, in a terminal emulator, run `x11vnc`. Not far from the end of the messages, you'll be informed about the opened connection with something like :

> The VNC desktop is:      mycomputersname:0

> PORT=5900
>
> ---
>
> Have you tried the x11vnc '-ncache' VNC client-side pixel caching
> feature yet?

- If you firewalled entering your server, open the given port (5900?) for the client.
- From your "client", launch Remmina, open the main window and add a connexion profile that point to the "server". Give it a name ; select "remmina VNC plugin" as protocol ; in the Basic tab, give the IP:Port of the "server" as server, like `192.168.1.25:5900`, with 5900 as the given port by the x11vnc command. No user nor password. Save & connect. The next time, you could directly connect with the named profile. Enjoy !

---

2. The client is waiting (usually on port 5500) for a server putting a
   connection (you need to know the client's IP). This is very usefull
   with server beyond NATed firewall. This way, you're also sure to
   share the server with the client you point.

- From your "client", use remmina, open the main window and add the connexion profile that wait for a "server". Give it a name like "VNC waiting for server" ; select "remmina VNC listener plugin" as protocol ; Listen on port 5500 ; no username nor password. Save & connect. The next time, you could directly connect with the named profile.
- If you firewalled entering your client, open the given port (5500) for the server
- From your "server" (directly or SSHed from the "client"), as the current user, in a terminal emulator, run `x11vnc -connect 192.168.1.14`. Not far from the end of the messages, you'll be informed about the opened connection. Enjoy !

---

It's just a beginning : NOTHING is secured !

Hope this help starting.